# JavaScript webpack - how to share variable between modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have JavaScript code after webpack built.

Code for the `bundle.js` looks like:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "rainloop/v/0.0.0/static/js/min/";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/*!********************!*\
  !*** ./dev/bundle.js ***!
  \********************/
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    __webpack_require__(/*! bootstrap */ 74)(__webpack_require__(/*! App/User */ 6));

/***/ },
/* 1 */
/*!*************************!*\
  !*** ./dev/Common/Utils.js ***!
  \*************************/
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {


    (function () {

     .... code for Utils.js module ...
        module.exports = Utils;

    }());

/***/ },
/* 2 */
/*!***************************!*\
  !*** external "window._" ***!
  \***************************/
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    module.exports = window._;

/***/ },
/* 6 */
/*!*************************!*\
  !*** ./dev/App/User.js ***!
  \*************************/
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {


    (function () {

      ... code for App/User.js module ....

        module.exports = new AppUser();

    }());

/***/ },
```

and so on.

Then I have tried to to declare

`var myVar;`

in the `Common/Utils` module which I want to import in the `App/User` module as

`Utils = __webpack_require__(/*! Common/Utils */ 1)`

but accessing it and updating as `Utils.myVar` is not working neither declaring it as `window.myVar` via `window` module above.

What should I do to have that variable shared between modules?

Comment: try to wrap that value into the object, like var params = { myVar: 'someValue' };. So you will always have a reference to an object.

Comment: @OleksandrMartyniuk problem it is a variable which is updated often as an observable for KnockoutJS. Simple I'm trying to get move that simple code http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/688373/ to modules where each ModalView is a separate module in webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up defining the global variable like

```
(function() {window.RL.myVal = new ko.subscribable(); })(window.RL = window.RL || {});
```

then I was able to access it and do subscribe/publish to it.

Answer (score 0):

export your module as an object:

```
var myVal = false;

// more stuff here

module.exports = { myVal, /* more stuff here */ };
```

in this case myVal will be changed for all importing modules as you reassign `module.exports.myVal` and not `var myVal` or vice versa.

To prevent this behavior store values in an object, so you'll have the same object reference both in exported module and in all importing:

```
var config = { myVal: false };

// more stuff here

module.exports = { config, /* more stuff here */ };
```

In this case you can freely modify config props (say myVal) unless you reassign `Utils.config` or `var config` itself.

Comment: Problem is that I don't have modules before webpack build. Need to get it done on a `bundle.js`. Should I add that manually as a new module and then export it and then do `__webpack_require__` for that module?

Comment: I don't see the code for Utils.js. As I see module.exports is the same for source and bundled code, it's just about the definition of variables and object references, you can do it on sources or on bundled code you provided.